# Не могу получить переменные с двух foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Добрый день! Помогите начинающему пожалуйста!
Получаю через api Яндекс.Диск список папок:

```
        $result = json_decode($result,true);
    foreach ($result['_embedded']['items'] as $file) { 
$extpath =  $file['name'];
```

Потом для каждой папки надо получить список файлов, я делаю еще один foreach внутри этого:

```
$result3 = json_decode($result3,true);
 foreach ($result3['_embedded']['items'] as $file3) {
          $extpath2 = $file3['name'];
```

И в конце всех циклов если я делаю return `$extpath;` то отображается только список папок. А если `return $extpath;`, то только список файлов во всех папках.

Внимание, вопрос: Как мне получить отдельно и список папок и список файлов?
Чтобы получилось так:

Folder1 >> File1, File2 
Folder2 >> File1, File2, File3

Спасибо!

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, полный код с двумя вложенными циклами

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо создать ассоциативный массив:
Примерный метод:

```
<?php
$folder = array();

$result = json_decode($result,true);
foreach ($result['_embedded']['items'] as $file) { 
$extpath =  $file['name'];

$result3 = json_decode($result3,true);
 foreach ($result3['_embedded']['items'] as $file3) {
          $extpath2 = $file3['name'];
array_push($folder[$extpath],$extpath2); 
}

}

print_r($folder);

?>
```

Так как вы показали обрывки кода(непонятно откуда у вас `$result3` ), я написал общую логику что вам надо сделать для получения результата.

```
Folder1 >> File1, File2 
Folder2 >> File1, File2, File3
```

PS В дальнейшем старайтесь полностью показывать код.